# Android: change images from PureData

Tags: android, image, puredata

So basically we have nearly finished our guitar tuner and just need to make the UI look nice.
We use Pure Data for all the audio processing in this and we want to represent the tuning being right or wrong based on images.
So if you need to tune up, an up image will be shown, when your in tune, an orange square lights up.
Right now we have some lines that move according to the sound and this works fine, but doesn't look very nice.

The way I was thinking of doing it was placing the "off" images in the XML file, so have a down arrow, up arrow and a center in tune square on the screen all set to be off (they are coloured grey), and as the tunings are being picked up the images change to ones that are coloured orange.

However when I try have it change the image, my program crashes, and I'm not too sure what I need to do to make the images change correctly.

A point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Link to pitchview class: http://pastebin.com/xJPU9su1

As you can see, I am trying to change the images in the onCanvas method, which currently draws lines onto the screen to represent tunings. Am I on the right track with it or do I have to change what I'm doing completely?

Comment: do you think that this is somehow related to using "puredata" (or rather "libpd") as the audio engine? i'm a bit under the impression that you are merely facing problems with your draw code in java. you might want to run your code in a debugger (or add loads of debugging printout) to see where it crashes and what might be the reason for it.

Answer (score -1):

I may be accused of dodging the question here (OK, I **am** dodging the question, but this may be useful anyway), but might it be easier to render an image with Pure Data's GEM library? Maybe you could do it like this:

```
|loadbang| ---- |create\ ---- |gemwin|

|noteTooSharp|-\ 
                \
|gemhead| ---- |spigot| ---- |pix_image foo/down_arrow.jpg| ---- |pix_draw|
```

This would only display your image when "noteTooSharp" produces a 1, which could be linked to the result from your tuner through (assuming that you have access to frequency.

```
|moses $freq|          <--------------  where $freq is the frequency
  |        \
  |         \
(too flat)  |moses $freq-1|
               |         |
            (nice!)    (too sharp)
```

I'm sorry if this isn't what you are looking for. I'm unsure whether GEM works on Android (under libpd). However, if you can use GEM I may also suggest http://puredata.info/downloads/gem/documentation/tutorial/primer, which is a very useful GEM tutorial.

Comment: Gem is currently not supported on opengGL-ES (like android)

Comment: you definitely don't want to use [pix_draw], unless you are using mid-nineties SGI hardware. use [pix_texture] and [rectangle] instead.